# wxpython and sockets. How do I send what is in my text box through sockets

Tags: python, wxpython

I created a text box called control that takes user input. Using the send button next to it I wanted to send whatever the user typed in it to a server. The problem being is that it doesn't send what is in the the text box. Instead the server receives " ". Just to knock to birds out with one stone also how would I make it so what is sent appears on the rectangle I drew?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\client with gui.py", line 37, in SendPress
    sent = control.GetValue()
NameError: global name 'control' is not defined



import socket
import wx

class WindowFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(500, 400))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("#E6E6E6")
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE, size =(410, 28), pos=(0,329))



        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 6667
        s.connect((host,port))


        sendbutton=wx.Button(self.panel, label ="Send", pos =(414,325), size=(65,35))
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SendPress, sendbutton )

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)  # <<< This was changed
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('black'))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('white'))
        dc.DrawRectangle(20, 20, 444, 280)
        self.Show(True)



    def SendPress(self, event):
        sent =control.GetValue()
        s.send(sent)

if __name__=="__main__": 
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Probably it is no good idea to use DC drawing commands for a simple chat client ([see also your other related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390383/wxpython-need-assistance-with-confusing-error)). See for a `StyledTextControl` example to have colored output.

Answer (score 0):

In the **SendPress** method, you need to call **self.control.GetValue()**, not **control.GetValue()**. The variable, **control** is not he same at the attribute **self.control**. That is why you are receiving the NameError.

To draw the text in wxPython, you would call dc.DrawText(). Please see the documentation and the wxPython demo for more information.

Comment: but now whenever I run it, type something in and press the send button it gives the error   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\client with gui.py", line 38, in SendPress
    s.send(sent)
NameError: global name 's' is not defined and also it still just sends " " to the server

Comment: You define "s" in **__init__**. The variable "s" is out of scope in SendPress, so you receive a NameError. It's just like when you tried to call **control**. That variable was out of scope too. You need to go read a tutorial on Python. Specifically study some articles on Python classes.