# wxpython. Need assistance with confusing error

Tags: python, sockets, wxpython

This code works for someone else on another computer but it won't seem to work for me. I am using python 2.7.7. It worked well for two other people but it just seems to not like me or my computer because whenever I run it, it gives me an error message. What do you guys think?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\python projects\client with gui.py", line 43, in <module>
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
  File "C:\Python27\python projects\client with gui.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)  # <<< This was changed
  File "C:\Python27\python projects\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_gdi.py", line 5215, in __init__
    _gdi_.PaintDC_swiginit(self,_gdi_.new_PaintDC(*args, **kwargs))
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ..\..\src\msw\dcclient.cpp(277) in wxPaintDCImpl::wxPaintDCImpl(): wxPaintDCImpl may be created only in EVT_PAINT handler!





import socket
import wx

class WindowFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(500, 400))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("#0B3861")
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE, size =(410, 28), pos=(0,329))
        self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)  # <<< This was changed
        # Sets up the socket connection
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 6667
        self.s.connect((host,port))

        # creates send button and binds to event
        sendbutton=wx.Button(self.panel, label ="Send", pos =(414,325), size=(65,35))
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SendPress, sendbutton )

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        #Draws white rectangle
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('black'))
        self.dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('white'))
        self.shapeRectangle=self.dc.DrawRectangle(20, 20, 444, 280)
        self.Show(True)


        # Sets the function of the send button
    def SendPress(self, event):
        self.sent = self.control.GetValue()
        self.s.send(self.sent)
        self.control.Clear()
        self.dc.DrawText(self.sent, 0, 300 )
        self.s.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error as you when running this code. Looking at the documentation linked below "A wx.PaintDC must be constructed if an application wishes to paint on the client area of a window from within an EVT_PAINT event handler."

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.PaintDC-class.html

Would you consider changing this to a Client DC? "A wx.ClientDC must be constructed if an application wishes to paint on the client area of a window from outside an EVT_PAINT event"

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ClientDC-class.html

Normally I think you would create the PaintDC within the method bound to the EVT_PAINT event, I checked a few examples of my code and I generally seem to use the ClientDC when I wish to look up attributes or affect the canvas from outside the Paint method.

To do this I would change:

```
self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
```

to:

```
self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)
```

Here is a full modified version of your code using the original PaintDC to do what I think you are trying to do.

```
import socket
import wx

class WindowFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(500, 400))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("#0B3861")
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE, size =(410, 28), pos=(0,329))
        self.textLog = []
        # Sets up the socket connection
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 6667
        self.s.connect((host,port))

        # creates send button and binds to event
        sendbutton=wx.Button(self.panel, label ="Send", pos =(414,325), size=(65,35))
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SendPress, sendbutton )

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        #Draws white rectangle
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel) 
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('black'))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('white'))
        dc.Clear()
        x, y = 20,20
        self.shapeRectangle=dc.DrawRectangle(x, y, 444, 280)
        fnt = dc.GetFont()        
        for i,line in enumerate(self.textLog):
            if i%2:
                dc.SetTextForeground(wx.RED)
            else:
                dc.SetTextForeground(wx.BLUE)
        dc.SetFont(fnt)
            dc.DrawText(line, x, y)
            y += dc.GetCharHeight()

        # Sets the function of the send button
    def SendPress(self, event):
        self.sent = self.control.GetValue()
        self.s.send(self.sent)
        self.control.Clear()
        self.textLog.append(self.sent)
        self.panel.Refresh()
        self.s.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: could you post an example please

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear, I changed:
    self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel) to self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)

Comment: It worked but I want it to print on the rectangle I drew and when I self.dc =wx.ClientDC(self.panel) to self.dc =wx.ClientDC(self.shapeRectangle) it gave me this error Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\python projects\client with gui.py", line 43, in <module> frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient') File "C:\Python27\python projects\client with gui.py", line 10, in init self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.shapeRectangle) # <<< This was changed AttributeError: 'WindowFrame' object has no attribute 'shapeRectangle

Comment: I see, well there are a few options here depending what you want to do, do you want to display all of the past sent messages or just the most recent? If you change your self.do.DrawText coordinates you can place this text on the rectangle, however it will be replaced when the rectangle is redrawn. What I suspect you want is to add text to a list, and then make the canvas repaint itself printing all the past messages, is this correct?

Comment: I have edited my response and added a version which does what I think you are trying to do, let me know if this is not correct. I tested it without the socket code as I know nothing about sockets and the like.

Comment: Thanks it worked but it doesn't allow to change the color of the text. I might just switch over to pyqt4. I hear it works well. what do you think?

Comment: You should be able to change the colour of the text, although it is tricky to do it for words in the same line. I see you have set the pen colour to Black, if you change that it should change the colour, you could alternate colours, or do different colours for each line. I have never looked at pyqt4, but thanks for telling me about it!

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to render the text yourself in a GUI toolkit? Look at the wxPython DEMO and the RichTextCtrl or the StyledTextCtrl. Both allow the setting of font size and color.

Comment: @nepix32 I agree, I was trying not change the source code as little as possible since the OP is about a PaintDC usage failure. I am just trying to demonstrate that wxPython can do these things. You are welcome to edit my response to improve it, or add your own answer, I would be interested in seeing more people's approaches.

Comment: @Weir_Doe: My comment was pointed at user3768136, questioning his other related question regarding a simple chat client. Of course your explanation of ClientDC vs. PaintDC nails it and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The example has quite a few problems:

- Absolute positioning instead of sizers
- No auto wrap on draw (it is generally a bad idea to render text yourself)
- Weird method of distinguishing send/recv (`i%2` ???)

In this case it would be much more appropriate to use a proper control for having coloured text. Plug in your send/receive mechanism as you see fit

```
import wx
from wx.stc import StyledTextCtrl

class WindowFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(500, 400))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("#0B3861")
        self.stc = StyledTextCtrl(self.panel, -1)
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sendbutton=wx.Button(self.panel, label ="Send")
        recvbutton=wx.Button(self.panel, label ="Receive")

        sendbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SendPress)
        recvbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.RecvPress)

        szmain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        szmain.Add(self.stc, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szsub = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        szsub.Add(self.control, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szsub.Add(sendbutton, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szsub.Add(recvbutton, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szmain.Add(szsub, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 0)

        self.panel.SetSizer(szmain)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        # define styles for stc, 0 red fore color, 1 blue fore color
        self.stc.StyleSetSpec(0, "fore:#FF0000")
        self.stc.StyleSetSpec(1, "fore:#0000FF")
        self.stc.SetWrapMode(True) #autowrap

    def add_text(self, text, style):
        curpos = self.stc.GetCurrentPos()
        self.stc.AddText(text)
        self.stc.AddText('\r\n')
        newpos = self.stc.GetCurrentPos()
        delta = newpos-curpos

        # consult the Scintilla doc (stc is based on it) to understand how styling works
        # http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Styling
        self.stc.StartStyling(curpos, 31) # mask 31 allows setting of styles
        self.stc.SetStyling(delta, style)
        self.stc.ScrollToEnd() # keep last line visible

        # Sets the function of the send button
    def SendPress(self, event):
        self.add_text(self._get_text(), 0)

        # Sets the function of the recv button
    def RecvPress(self, event):
        self.add_text(self._get_text(), 1)

    def _get_text(self):
        text = self.control.GetValue()
        self.control.Clear()
        return text


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Look in the wxPython demo how to use the `StyledTextControl` (based on Scintilla). And last but not least it made me learn `STC`.

Comment: StyledTextControl looks like a good route, I have spent some time looking at Scintilla today, thanks for bringing that to my attention!